# What is the relationship between the standard deviation of a random intercept and the value of the integer scalar?

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, standard-deviation, random-effects-model

I fit a mixed-effects logistic regression model in R with the following formula:

`glmer.traditional <- glmer(AGENT.EXPONENCE ~ ASPECT + (1 | LEMMA), data = hdtpassive, family = binomial(link="logit"))`

The standard deviation for the random intercept is really high:

```
Random effects:
Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
LEMMA  (Intercept) 400.4    20.01   
Number of obs: 438, groups:  LEMMA, 174
```

When, however, I use the following formula, the standard deviation plummets:

`glmer.traditional <- glmer(AGENT.EXPONENCE ~ ASPECT + (1 | LEMMA), data = hdtpassive, family = binomial(link="logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 25)`

```
Random effects:
Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
LEMMA  (Intercept) 27.28    5.223   
Number of obs: 438, groups:  LEMMA, 174
```

The `nAGQ` is the scalar that is used for approximating the log-likelihood. Higher values for this argument produce more accurate approximations, but come at the expense of speed.

I have two questions about this:

1. How does the value of the integer scalar affect the standard deviation of the random intercept? I don't know how the Gauss-Hermite quadrature works.
2. Are there guidelines on the interpretation of standard deviations for random intercepts? E.g., is a really high standard deviation a warning sign of some kind?

Comment: A bit of (unsolicited) advice: the way this question is written, it appears at first glance to be highly language-specific and basically a programming question, which would be [off-topic here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You can improve both the amount of traffic to your question as well as the probability that it remains open (not closed by mods) by editing the question to de-emphasize the parts that are specific to R and the lme4 package, and emphasize instead the general statistical parts of the question. _Minimally_, you would need to explain what `nAGQ` is.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @JakeWestfall. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is more of a jumping-off point for those more experienced than I.  I just did a bit of preliminary research, for those who may be interested.  To answer question (1), by pulling from [the `glmer` documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-17/topics/glmer)...

> **nAGQ**: integer scalar - the number of points per axis for evaluating the adaptive Gauss-Hermite approximation to the log-likelihood. Defaults to 1, corresponding to the Laplace approximation. Values greater than 1 produce greater accuracy in the evaluation of the log-likelihood at the expense of speed. A value of zero uses a faster but less exact form of parameter estimation for GLMMs by optimizing the random effects and the fixed-effects coefficients in the penalized iteratively reweighted least squares step.

So, increasing `nAGQ` will (i) take longer, and (ii) increase accuracy of the log-likelihood evaluation.

An answer to part (2) can be seen [in this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/173271/213806).  An explanation of the intercept term itself is seen [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113777/importance-of-intercept-term-in-regression-equation).  In the comments it is noted that:

> "If all the variables, both predictors and response, are centered, then you don't need the intercept term. Instead, you take away 1 df for residual because of centering the response variable. Once you have done all that, it is equivalent to including the intercept in the model where the variables are not centered."